# .click() function to work with whole document but not with one div

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function which hides a div when clicks anywhere on the document:

```
    $(document).click(function() {
    if($('#child_link').css("display") == "block"){
       $('#child_link').css("display","none");
      }
    });
```

I want to add an exception for one div '#child_link'. How do I perform this?

I tried:

```
    $(document).not('#child_link').click(function() {
    if($('#child_link').css("display") == "block"){
       $('#child_link').css("display","none");
      }
    });
```

But it adds an exception for whole document.

Answer (score 0):

Check if target is not child_link

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($('#child_link').css("display") == "block" && e.target.id != "child_link") {
        //                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        $('#child_link').css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Also note that you can use .hide()//.is(':visible')

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($('#child_link').is(":visible") && e.target.id != "child_link") {
        $('#child_link').hide()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if( e.target.id != 'child_link'){
        if($('#child_link').css("display") == "block"){
            $('#child_link').css("display","none");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try `$('*').not('#child_link')` instead of `$(document).not('#child_link')`

Answer (score 0):

On click check div-id , if it is not"child_link" write that in if.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if( e.target.id != 'child_link'){
        if($('#child_link').css("display") == "block"){
            $('#child_link').css("display","none");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [delegated event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on("click", "*:not('#child_link')", function(){
    $('#child_link').toggle();
});
```

It will fire for everything except the child link.
[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) will toggle between hiding and displaying the element

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

http://jsfiddle.net/GjTgf/1/

```
$('#child_link').click(function(e) { 
  e.stopPropagation();
 })

 $(function(){
  $(document).click(function(){  
  $('#child_link').hide(); 
  });
});
```

Hope this helps to solve your issue above.